# Model not being passed to controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've been learning Laravel and am trying to get a form in the login view to bind to a model and then have the model passed to a controller, I'm then passing the model to another the dashboard view to display the username attribute of it to test if it is working. The username is not being displayed therefore the model doesn't seem to be binding.

I've looked through the documentation and can't figure out what else I need to do/what I have done wrong.

Thanks

Model

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Theo
 * Date: 25/01/2018
 * Time: 19:35
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Models;


class User
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
}
```

Controller

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;


    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $user = new User();
            return view('pages.login.index')->with('user', $user);
        }

        public function attemptLogin(User $user){

            return view('pages.dashboard.index')->with('user', $user);
        }
    }
```

Login view

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
    <div id="login-container">
      <div class="login-box">
        {!! Form::model($user, ['action' => 'LoginController@attemptLogin']) !!}

          {!! Form::text('username', @$user->username) !!}
          {!! Form::password('password', @$user->password) !!}

          {!! Form::submit('Login') !!}

          {!! Form::close() !!}
      </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Dashboard view

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
    <h3>Welcome to the dashboard! {{{ $user->username }}}</h3>
@stop
```

Routes

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('players');
});

/*
Route::get('/players/{uid}', function ($uid) {
    return view('players' . $uid);
});
*/

Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

Route::get('login', 'LoginController@index');
Route::post('login/attemptLogin', 'LoginController@attemptLogin');
```

Comment: Honestly, I think you have more reading to do.  Lots of problems with your code so it seems you've just glanced at the documentation and not really read/understood it.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the problems? I want to make sure I'm doing everything right

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Theo
 * Date: 25/01/2018
 * Time: 19:35
 */


namespace App\Http\Controllers\Models;


class User
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
}
```

to this. put the file into app folder and add extends Model

```
<?php
namespace App;
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Theo
 * Date: 25/01/2018
 * Time: 19:35
 */

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['username'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

Comment: @Theo Crawly check it now. I have made improvements. If this solved your issue let others know by marking it as the correct answer. happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks, the username still isn't showing on the dashboard so the form must not be binding

Answer (score 1):

You should create model using artisan command line by typing 
`php artisan make:model User`
which will then create a model `User` for you in `app/` folder.

You are creating model inside `app/Http/Controllers` which is used for storing Controllers only.

If you want a basic auth system you can run `php artisan make:auth` which will genrate a bootstrap boilerplate with basic auth system

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've remade the model using the command but I still don't think the form is binding to it or it is not being passed to the controller

Comment: change  `new User()` to  `User::all()` it might solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any route parameters.

In order to use Route-Model Binding, you need to either use a resource route or specify a route parameter equal to the controller method argument's name.

So if you have:

```
    public function attemptLogin(User $user) {}
```

To have an instance of User injected, you need to have a route parameter that matches $user:

```
    Route::post('login/attemptLogin/{user}', 'LoginController@attemptLogin');
```

However, I'm not exactly sure why you'd be trying to attempt a login into a specific user rather than provide the username as a request variable.

Comment: Thanks, changing that gives me the following errror. I've looked online and can't find a solution to it. Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: login/attemptLogin/{user}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\panel\resources\views\pages\login\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the namespace of your User model to `App\Http\Controllers\Models\User` you need to update the `config/auth.php` file.

Search for this code:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

and change the model section to: `'model' => App\Http\Controllers\Models\User::class,`

BTW: Its not a good idea moving your Models below the `Http` folder because you mixing the HTTP layer with your business layer.